# Optimize vtk color map speed for a 3D volume

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, vtk

I testing a code written with vtk and pyqt5. The code works fine but the problem I have is setting the color map. In the code below, I decided to use matplotlib cmaps as the have a whole lot. I have 2 button I made in pyqt5 for changing the color map of the plotted 3D volume as shown in the last function. The only problem I have is that changing the color map freezes the ui and it takes about 60+ second to map all the points. Converting my array to range 0-255 will help but I want to keep the resolution as is. Is there a way to improve this?

I tried using the vtk LUT but it only takes in unsignedchar (0-255).
Is there a better way to write this? This is my first time using vtk and there's not a whole lot out there to reference. My code could also be written differently but I'm not sure how to go about it.

NOTE: The code might not run well for you guys since I tried deleting lines out to shorten it

```
import numpy as np
import vtk
from vtk.util import numpy_support
from vtk.qt.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor import QVTKRenderWindowInteractor
import tifffile as tiff
from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap

import io
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QFileDialog)
from PyQt5 import uic
import sys

import pathlib
file_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()


class ThreeDPlot(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ThreeDPlot, self).__init__()

        print(file_path)

        uic.loadUi(f"{file_path}/vtk_ui_test.ui", self)
        vtk.vtkObject.GlobalWarningDisplayOff()

        self.imdata = vtk.vtkImageData()
        self.colorFunc = vtk.vtkColorTransferFunction()
        self.opacityFunc = vtk.vtkPiecewiseFunction()
        self.volumeProperty = vtk.vtkVolumeProperty()
        self.volumeMapper = vtk.vtkSmartVolumeMapper()
        self.ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
        self.interactor = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor()
        self.volume = vtk.vtkVolume()
        self.plot_layout.addWidget(self.interactor)
        self.interactor.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(self.ren)
        self.iren = self.interactor.GetRenderWindow().GetInteractor()

        self.xy_image_property = vtk.vtkImageProperty()
        self.xy_slice_val = vtk.vtkImageSlice()
        self.xy_mapper = vtk.vtkImageSliceMapper()
        self.xy_imdata_slice = vtk.vtkImageData()

        self.xz_image_property = vtk.vtkImageProperty()
        self.xz_slice_val = vtk.vtkImageSlice()
        self.xz_mapper = vtk.vtkImageSliceMapper()
        self.xz_imdata_slice = vtk.vtkImageData()

        self.yz_image_property = vtk.vtkImageProperty()
        self.yz_slice_val = vtk.vtkImageSlice()
        self.yz_mapper = vtk.vtkImageSliceMapper()
        self.yz_imdata_slice = vtk.vtkImageData()

        self.load_volume_button.clicked.connect(self.load_volume)
        self.transform = vtk.vtkTransform()
        # print(dir(self.volumeMapper))
        # print(dir(self.colorFunc))

        self.get_color = ['Accent', 'Blues', 'BrBG', 'BuGn', 'BuPu', 'CMRmap', 'Dark2', 'GnBu', 'Greens', 'Greys',
                                'OrRd', 'Oranges', 'PRGn', 'Paired', 'Pastel1', 'Pastel2', 'PiYG', 'PuBu', 'PuBuGn', 'PuOr',
                                'PuRd', 'Purples', 'RdBu', 'RdGy', 'RdPu', 'RdYlBu', 'RdYlGn', 'Reds', 'Set1', 'Set2', 'Set3',
                                'Spectral', 'Wistia', 'YlGn', 'YlGnBu', 'YlOrBr', 'YlOrRd', 'afmhot', 'autumn','binary', 'bone',
                                'brg', 'bwr', 'cool', 'coolwarm', 'copper', 'cubehelix', 'flag', 'gist_earth', 'gist_gray',
                                'gist_heat', 'gist_ncar', 'gist_rainbow', 'gist_stern', 'gist_yarg', 'gnuplot', 'gnuplot2',
                                'gray', 'hot', 'hsv', 'jet', 'nipy_spectral', 'ocean', 'pink', 'prism', 'rainbow', 'seismic',
                                'spring', 'summer', 'tab10', 'tab20', 'tab20b', 'tab20c', 'terrain', 'winter']
        
        self.current_index = 0
        self.prev_cmap_button.clicked.connect(self.change_cmap)
        self.next_cmap_button.clicked.connect(self.change_cmap)

        # Add the interactor as a child widget to the plot layout
        self.plot_layout.addWidget(self.interactor)
        self.show()

    def load_volume(self):
        # Show a file dialog for selecting the input file
        file_name, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 'Open File', '', 'TIFF Files (*.tif *.tiff)')

        if not file_name:
            return

        self.data = np.rot90(tiff.imread(file_name) , k=2)
        # self.data = (self.data / 65535) * 255

        self.imdata.SetDimensions(self.data.shape)
        self.imdata.SetSpacing(1,1,1)
        self.imdata.SetOrigin(0,0,0)
        self.imdata.GetPointData().SetScalars(
            numpy_support.numpy_to_vtk(self.data.ravel(order='F'), deep=False))
        # print("array type: ", self.data.dtype)

        # Calculate the data range of the volume
        self.data_range = np.abs(self.data).max()

        # Create transfer function
        self.opacityFunc.RemoveAllPoints()
        self.opacityFunc.AddPoint(0, 0)
        self.opacityFunc.AddPoint(self.data_range, 1.0)

        # Set transfer function
        self.volumeProperty.SetColor(self.colorFunc)
        self.volumeProperty.SetScalarOpacity(self.opacityFunc)
        self.volumeProperty.SetInterpolationTypeToLinear()
        self.volumeProperty.ShadeOn()
        self.volumeProperty.SetAmbient(0.4)
        self.volumeProperty.SetDiffuse(0.6)
        self.volumeProperty.SetSpecular(0.2)
        self.volumeProperty.SetSpecularPower(10)

        # Create volume mapper
        self.volumeMapper.SetInputData(self.imdata)
        self.volumeMapper.SetBlendModeToMaximumIntensity()


        # Create volume
        self.volume.SetMapper(self.volumeMapper)
        self.volume.SetProperty(self.volumeProperty)
        # self.volume.SetScale(3,1,1)
        self.transform.Scale(1,1,1)# backTofront, toToBot, leftToright
        self.volume.SetUserTransform(self.transform)
        self.xy_slice_val.SetUserTransform(self.transform)
        self.xz_slice_val.SetUserTransform(self.transform)
        self.yz_slice_val.SetUserTransform(self.transform)

        self.ren.AddVolume(self.volume)
        self.ren.SetBackground(0, 0, 0)
        self.ren.ResetCamera()

        # Create interactor
        self.interactor.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(self.ren)

        # Start rendering
        self.iren.SetInteractorStyle(vtk.vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera())
        self.iren.Initialize()
        self.interactor.Initialize()
        self.interactor.Start()

    def change_cmap(self):

        if self.sender() == self.next_cmap_button:
            self.current_index = (self.current_index + 1) % len(self.get_color)
        else:
            self.current_index = (self.current_index - 1) % len(self.get_color)

        cmap = get_cmap(self.get_color[self.current_index])
        self.cmap_label.setText(self.get_color[self.current_index])

        for i in range(65536):
            rgba = cmap(i/65535)
            self.colorFunc.AddRGBPoint(i, rgba[0], rgba[1], rgba[2])

        self.volumeProperty.SetColor(self.colorFunc)
        self.iren.Render()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = ThreeDPlot()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```